# PadRight in string of arrays doesn't add chars

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console-application

I created array of strings which includes strings with Length from 4 to 6. I am trying to `PadRight` 0's to get length for every element in array to 6.

```
string[] array1 =
{
    "aabc", "aabaaa", "Abac", "abba", "acaaaa"
};

for (var i = 0; i <= array1.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (array1[i].Length < 6)
    {
        for (var j = array1[i].Length; j <= 6; j++)
        {

            array1[i] = array1[i].PadRight(6 - array1[i].Length, '0');

        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
}
```

Right now the program writes down the exact same strings I have in array without adding 0's at the end. I made a little research and found some informations about that strings are immutable, but still there are some example with changing strings inside, but I couldn't find any with PadRight or PadLeft and I fell like there must be a way to do it, but I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas on how to fix that issue?

Comment: Hover the mouse over the `PadRight()` method. Read the tooltip. Think about what it says. You shouldn't come here to ask people to read the documentation to you. You should work to develop the capacity to read the documentation yourself. If you read and understand the documentation and you still can't figure out what's happening, *then* that would be a good time to ask a question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for answer. Well... Since I am learning I thought I should just ask, but Your are right and I should do things on my own. I will think about it next time for sure before posting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `PadRight` is the *total* length you want. You've specified `6 - array1[i].Length` - and as all your strings start off with at least 3 characters, you're padding to *at most* 3 characters, so it's not doing anything.

You don't need your inner loop, and your outer loop condition is more conventionally written as `<`. This is one way I'd write that code:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] array =
        {
            "aabc", "aabaaa", "Abac", "abba", "acaaaa"
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = array[i].PadRight(6, '0');
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In fact I'd probably use `foreach`, or even `Select`, but that's a different matter. I've left this using an array to be a bit closer to your original code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Now I see my mistake. I tried to complicate things for no reason. Now that code works just fine and I might play a bit with foreach as well. Thanks!